# How to prioritize backlog in YouTrack?

Tags: scrum, agile, prioritization

In Youtrack, how would I keep track of issues that are suitable for inclusion in the next sprint? The backlog is of course larger than just the next sprint.

Generally when going over the issue list we see stories/tasks that would be suitable. We can drag them to the top of the list, but:

- We are usually looking at filtered views at that moment, so the 'top' is not absolute.
- We have Youtrack set up to sort on change date, so all kinds of items 'jump' to the top

The best I can think of is using a 'Next sprint' tag. This would require:

- Removing the tag if an item is put into the sprint
- Regularly reviewing the items tagged this way, because priorities can change

Does anyone have a better idea?

There are plenty of questions about prioritization here, but they are about the process (determining value etc.), and not the practical implementation (in YouTrack).

I'm asking from the viewpoint of the PO/SM.

Answer (score 1):

The best documentation I can reference you to which provides a method to create a "saved search."

> Prioritize the Backlog﻿
> You can reorder your backlog directly on the board to reflect your current prioritization. You can also add subtasks to parent issues directly in the backlog.

> The ability to reorder issues in the backlog is limited to members of the group that has permission to update the saved search that is used for issues in the backlog. This option is stored in the settings for the saved search. You can also find on the same source, how to edit "saved searches". hope that helps.

[JetBrains YouTrack Source Links - #Prioritizing-the-Backlog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/cloud/Work-with-Backlog.html#Prioritizing-the-Backlog)